# How to take sum of column on grouping rows of column 1 in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pymysql

This is my data frame attached in image and I want to sum as per the first column where ?? represent no value for that entry 
[DATAFRAME IMAGE SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hybMV.png)
I want to write code to have an output like below
HWK 0
CSP 0
DCF 0
I want to sum the values only if n/a or ?? occurs then ignore it and do the sum so that I can iterate through all the data frame for the same procedure

```
HWK      0 
CSP     ?? 
DCF      0 
BM_IO   ?? 
CS      ?? 
os      ?? 
CS       0 
ESC      0 
ESC      0 
DCF      0 
DLHLTL  ?? 
CSP      0 
CSP      0 
ESC      0 
CSP     ??
```

Comment: Can you please post the sample as text and not image, also your expected output please, it will be easier to copy the data thatway. Thanks

Comment: HWK 0
CSP ??
DCF 0
BM_IO ??
CS ??
os ??
CS 0
ESC 0
ESC 0
DCF 0
DLHLTL ??
CSP 0
CSP 0
ESC 0
CSP ??

Comment: Can you please post the data in your question as a proper dataframe, also your expected output. Thank you.

Comment: I m copying dataframe but it is pasting as text only

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your source DataFrame has columns `code` and `quantity`,
and `quantity` is of type `object` (has both strings and numbers).

Then, one of possible solutions is as follows:

- `df.quantity.astype(str)` - Convert `quantity` values to strings
  (`np.nan` values are converted to *'nan'* string).
- `.str.isdigit()` - Check whether the above string has only digit chars.
- `[...]` - The above booolean list selects which rows to select (from `df`).
- `.groupby('code').sum()` - Having such a "limited" table, you can
  perform all processing with a single `groupby` (by `code`) and `sum`
  for each group.

To sum up:

```
df[df.quantity.astype(str).str.isdigit()].groupby('code').sum()
```